# Rename output file in uppercase without the extensions bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, filenames

In a shell i browse several files to reformat them, so i generate an output with the name of the file + a .cpy extension.

For exemple i have test.des.utf8 that i generate to test.des.utf8.cpy, what i would like to do is to go from test.des.utf8 to TEST.cpy.

I tried something like that but it didn't work for me:

```
"$f" "${f%.txt}.text"
```

Here is my shell with the output redirection :

```
for f in $SOURCE_DIRECTORY 
do 
    b=$(basename "$f")
    echo "Generating $f file in copy.."; 
    awk -F ';' '
$1=="TABLE" && $3==" " {
  printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2;
  next
}
{
  result = $2
  if ($2 ~ /^Numérique [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/) {
    nr=split($2,a,"[ .]")
    result = "PIC 9(" a[2] ")"
    if (nr == 3) {
      result = result ".v9(" a[3] ")"
    }    
  }
  sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", result);
  printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, result;
}' "$f" > "$TARGET_DIRECTORY/$b.cpy"
done
```

Comment: `f='test.des.utf8'; nf="${f%%.*}"; nf="${nf@U}.cpy"; echo "$nf"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` parameter expansion makes both upper-casing the expansion of a variable and removing part of the resulting string easy:

```sh
filename=test.des.utf8

# Upper-cased version of filename
newfilename="${filename^^}"
# Remove everything from the first . to the end and add a new extension
newfilename="${newfilename%%.*}.cpy"

# Remove echo when happy with results
echo cp "$filename" "$newfilename"
```

Comment: can i do this in one line like that : "${filename^^%%.*}.cpy" ?

Comment: @YoussefHammouma If you know the full extension you want to remove ahead of time, with something like `"$(basename "${filename^^}" .DST.UTF8).cpy"`

Comment: Or if you can use zsh instead of bash, `"${(U)filename%%.*}.cpy"`

Comment: Could also be done entirely with awk, including processing all files

Comment: @LéaGris You could say that about practically any programming language, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If using Gnu Awk, you could process all your files with this stand-alone awk script:

`myAwkScript`

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  targetDir="./"
}

# Before processing each file passed as argument
BEGINFILE {
  # Split the file path
  i=split(FILENAME, splitpath, "/")

  # File name part without path is last element
  name = splitpath[i]

  # Split file name on dot
  split(name, splitname, ".")

  # Compose outputPath to targetDir with:
  # Uppercase first part before dot and .cpy suffix
  outputPath = targetDir toupper(splitname[1]) ".cpy"

  # Erase the content of the outputPath
  printf "" > outputPath
}

# Your original awk script will process each line of each file
$1=="TABLE" && $3==" " {
  # Changed this to append to the outputPath file
  printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2 >> outputPath
  next
}
{
  result = $2
  if ($2 ~ /^Numérique [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/) {
    nr=split($2,a,"[ .]")
    result = "PIC 9(" a[2] ")"
    if (nr == 3) {
      result = result ".v9(" a[3] ")"
    }    
  }
  sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", result)

  # Changed this to append to the outputPath file
  printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, result >> outputPath
}
```

make script executable:

```sh
chmod +x ./myAwkScript
```

run script to process all your files:

```sh
./myAwkScript somewhere/*
```